# Export PHP array to csv - save window fails to open and data appears in POST Response instead

Tags: php, ajax, export-to-csv

I have saved the data from an array to `$_SESSION`. I have a button which is linked to a click event that calls an AJAX function, and that AJAX function refers to another PHP file that has the export to CSV code.

When I click the button, I can see in Firebug that the POST is successful, and the Response shows the data in a nicely formatted CSV.

How do I get this to open in a Save dialog so the user can save the contents to CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV data is being returned to the AJAX caller and won't be downloaded.  You need to have a link that the user is directed to that outputs the CSV file and the browser will initiate the download.